# Autohotkey for disabling Alt-menu not working on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, autohotkey

I first discovered Auto Hot Key when I needed to disable the alt-menu option with the script

`~LAlt Up:: return`

It worked back there, but its been a couple of months since I noticed it stopped working.
 I already have tried run AutoHotKey as administrator with no luck.
 I don't have idea what could be causing this.
 I have another ahk script for overlaying windows, for the matter of conflit, but even when I disable it the alt-menu script still doesn't work. Help.

Comment: Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48701137/disabling-alt-menu-bar-activation-with-autohotkey-not-working-on-windows-8?answertab=active#tab-top).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed, since some time `~LAlt up::return` does not work anymore. I beleive there was some change in Windows keyboard event system.

After some experiments I've found working code:

```
LAlt::
    send {LAlt down}
return

LAlt up::
    send {LAlt up}
return
```

And this also works:

```
LAlt::LAlt
```

Comment: I think this is related to Autohotkey version, because I have other PC with latest Windows 10 and old Autohotkey v1.1.16.05 and old solution works. Your first solution works perfectly. Solution "LAlt::LAlt" has issues: hotkey "Alt-Win-Key" leaves Win key stuck down.